# how to combine FrameWork2.0 in my installation?

Tags: c#, installation

i want to distribute my C# program and i want to combine

FrameWork2.0 in my installation.

how i can do it - without download FW2.0 from the Web ?

i need that the FW2.0 will be part of my installation and when the

customer will install the program - the FW2.0 will be install (without internet)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your setup project properties.
2. Click on the Prerequisites button.
3. Choose "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application".
4. Click Ok.
5. Rebuild the project.

Now the Framework 2.0 with other dependent packages should be created along with the setup in your project output folder.

Comment: thank's for the help, and how to combine ActiveSync 4.5 in my installation ?

Comment: If ActiveSync is one of the dependencies .. then it will also be included .. or else in the same dialog if you can See ActiveSync in the list .. then check it .. 

If it is not present in the prerequisites list .. then you can create custom installation packages .. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785916/net-c-install-project-including-other-packages-problem/3786105#3786105

Comment: i can's see ActiveSync in the list - and i use it

Comment: Then you can create your own packages and add it to your setup dependencies .. check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: and what i need to check if my program need to work with access on computer that dont has access ? (where is the MDAC)

Comment: You can add MDAC as merge module to your setup project.
How TO: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320788

Answer (score 0):

Place .NET 2.0 Redist package into you install, see

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5&displaylang=en